# How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, string, aggregate, concatenation

Basically the question is how to get from this:

```
foo_id   foo_name
1        A
1        B
2        C
```

to this:

```
foo_id   foo_name
1        A B
2        C
```

Comment: @barlop fixed that by editing question and answers.

Answer (score 673, accepted):

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' ') FROM table GROUP BY id;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

From the link above, `GROUP_CONCAT`: This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Answer (score 171):

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT( string SEPARATOR ' ') FROM table GROUP BY id
```

More details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

From the link above, `GROUP_CONCAT`: This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Comment: the resulting column has a [limit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3785928/1500392) in characters. 
see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3785928/1500392) and the docs
:)

Comment: isn't it foo_id?

Answer (score 23):

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' ') FROM table GROUP BY id;
```

:-
In MySQL, you can get the concatenated values of expression combinations
. To eliminate duplicate values, use the **DISTINCT** clause. To sort values in the result, use the ORDER BY clause. To sort in *reverse order*, add the ***DESC*** (descending) keyword to the name of the column you are sorting by in the ORDER BY clause. The default is ascending order; this may be specified explicitly using the ASC keyword. The default separator between values in a group is comma (“,”). To specify a separator explicitly, use SEPARATOR followed by the string literal value that should be inserted between group values. To eliminate the separator altogether, specify **SEPARATOR ''**.

```
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
             [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
                 [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
             [SEPARATOR str_val])
```

OR

```
mysql> SELECT student_name,
    ->     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT test_score
    ->               ORDER BY test_score DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
    ->     FROM student
    ->     GROUP BY student_name;
```

Answer (score 21):

The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024 characters, so we first do:

```
SET group_concat_max_len=100000000;
```

and then, for example:

```
SELECT pub_id,GROUP_CONCAT(cate_id SEPARATOR ' ') FROM book_mast GROUP BY pub_id
```

Comment: The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a _default value_ of **1024** characters. [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: What is the scope of this `group_concat_max_len` config? Current connection/session, or will it affect other clients?

Comment: @FrozenFlame:
> If no modifier is present, SET changes the session variable. If the variable has no session value, an error occurs.

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-system-variables.html

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question but merely adds helpful information. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A
[proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve
its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make
it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer
to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 20):

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(name as CHAR)) FROM table GROUP BY id
```

Will give you a comma-delimited string

Answer (score 12):

Great answers.
I also had a problem with NULLS and managed to solve it by including a COALESCE inside of the GROUP_CONCAT.  Example as follows:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(name,'') SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM table 
GROUP BY id;
```

Hope this helps someone else