# Select an array per row?

Tags: mysql, select, arrays

I have 2 tables:

```
1. products
- product_id
- title
2. product_categories
- product_id
- category_id
```

Each product can have more than one category. I store this information in the product_categories table. I want to be able to SELECT all the category_ids when I select a product in 1 query. How can I do this? I have the following so far, but it will only select 1 category id:

```
SELECT
  p.*,
  (SELECT
     category_id
   FROM 
     product_categories
   WHERE product_id = p.product_id) as category_ids
FROM
   products AS p
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? An example would help.

Comment: like a multi-dim array for each row. So all the general product information could be retrieve in PHP like $row['title'] but the categories would be a further array $row['product_categories'][0] would get the first product category id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a left join, Group By, and GROUP_CONCAT

[How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

```
SELECT products.*, GROUP_CONCAT(category_id SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM products LEFT JOIN product_categories
                ON product_categories.product_id = products.product_id
GROUP BY product_id;
```

Comment: Very close to what I need, however I need it to return it as an Array. I will be using it with sphinx's MVA datatype.

Answer (score 0):

select products.*,product_categories from 
left outer join product_categories on product_categories.product_id = products.product_id