# Concatenating Multiple Rows in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table structure that looks like this:

```
ID   String
-----------
1     A
1     Test
1     String
2     Dear
2     Person
```

I need the final output to look like this:

```
ID  FullString
--------------------
1   A, Test, String
2   Dear, Person
```

I am really lost on how to approach this... I looked on a couple examples online but they seemed to be VERY complex... this seems like it should be a real easy problem to solve in sql.

Thank you for all assistance!

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(String) AS FullString
     FROM TABLE
     GROUP BY ID
```

There are additional parameters available for GROUP_CONCAT to control sequence and separation.  GROUP_CONCAT is MySQL specific.