# SQL Concatenate and group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a TSQL version of group_concat
Simmilar to the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732244/concatinating-multiple-rows-in-sql):

```
Policy   Destination   ID
-------------------------
PolA     DestA         1    
PolA     DestA         2    
PolB     DestB         3     
PolB     DestB         4    
PolC     DestC         5
PolC     DestC         6
PolC     DestD         7
```

### The output should look like this:

```
PolA   DestA   1,2
PolB   DestB   3,4
PolC   DestC   5,6
PolC   DestD   7
```

The grouping is on the uniqueness of both the first 2 columns, and then a concatenated output on the third.

I found [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f09d4166-2030-41fe-b86e-392fbc94db53/tsql-equivalent-for-groupconcat-function?forum=transactsql) but it only take into account 2 columns

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Please tag which dbms you are using.  If this is SQL Server, add the tag.  Also, tag which SQL Server you are using.  STRING_AGG may not exist in earlier version. Secondly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: As he wrote `TSQL` in the question, we can assume the DBMS as `SQL Server` and i suggested that edit already. @user5947977 - Did you try my answer?

Comment: @user5947977 - Please mark the answer as useful(upvote) also as it worked for your issue.

Comment: thank you all, noted for future, the answer below worked a treat :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
SELECT G.Policy, G.Destination,
    stuff(
    (select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + U.ID
    from yourtable U
    WHERE U.Policy = G.Policy and U.Destination = G.Destination
    order by U.Policy
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS IDs
FROM yourtable G group BY G.Policy, G.Destination
```

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL Synax:

```
SELECT Policy, Destination, STRING_AGG ( [ID], ',' ) IDs
FROM Table
```

Comment: This method assumes you using SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 0):

I just create the `PolA` example table for you, just replace the CTE as your table, try below:

```
WITH ABC
as
(
select   'PolA' as Policy,'DestA' as Destination,'1' as ID  
UNION ALL 
select 'PolA','DestA','2'
)

SELECT Policy, Destination,
 STUFF((SELECT ',' + A.ID FROM ABC as A WHERE A.Policy = B.Policy FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as ID
FROM ABC as B
GROUP BY B.policy, B.Destination
```