# Query for SELECT all users who speak all the specified languages

Tags: sql, database, join

I've a table we have userids of people and the langauges they can speak. just two columns, userid and language.

I want to find all those users who can speak hindi AND english AND german AND french.
How should I write this query ? I cannot use Inner Join 4 times. Problem being the check for number of languages might increase, I might want to check for more languages.

userid | language
      1 | english
      4 | english
      1 | french
      1 | german
 .................

Comment: You can use `group by` and `count`. Google "Relational Division"

Comment: Or [see this link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: COUNT(*) and GROUP BY would only give you how many languages each user spoke, not which languages.

Comment: @Chris. You use `WHERE language in('english','hindi', 'french','german')` , `GROUP BY userid` then check `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT language) = 4`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If using MySQL, you could do something like (to be debugged, not tested):

```
SELECT userid FROM (
    SELECT userid, GROUP_CONCAT(language SEPARATOR ',') AS languages
    FROM UserLanguage 
    ORDER BY userid ASC, language ASC 
    GROUP BY userid)
WHERE languages LIKE '%english%french%german%hindi%';
```

(the languages in the LIKE clause have to be sorted)

[How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

---

Or maybe faster:

```
SELECT userid 
FROM UserLanguage 
WHERE language IN ('fr', 'en, 'de', 'hi') 
GROUP BY userid 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(language)) >= 4
```

Comment: +1 for the group-having solution - does the same as what I suggested, but with a simpler query :)

Comment: Thanks marvin. It works great. I couldn't understand why >=4 has been added at the end and I suppose the check should have been for =4 only as only 4 languages are being checked for? Could you elaborate this a bit. thanks

Comment: I've been waiting about 10 years for a built-in GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function in SQL Server.  Still waiting.  +1 btw, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT userid
FROM (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM mytable
    WHERE language IN ('hindi','german','french','english')
    GROUP BY userid
) AS t
WHERE cnt = 4;
```

Comment: It is - the only thing that's still a bit shaky about it is that you have to know how many languages you're looking for. It's usually not a problem if you use PHP or another server side language to construct the query, but then again, who knows - the OP isn't specific about this :).

Comment: Could you load the languages into a table variable @Languages, then do `WHERE language IN (SELECT * FROM @Languages)` and have `declare @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Languages)` and `HAVING cnt = @Count`?

Comment: Aye, `having` is the way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [correlated subquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638.aspx), like this:

```
SELECT UserId
FROM UserLanguage UL1
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UserLanguage UL2 WHERE UL2.UserId = UL1.UserId
        AND UL2.Language = 'english') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UserLanguage UL2 WHERE UL2.UserId = UL1.UserId
        AND UL2.Language = 'hindi') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UserLanguage UL2 WHERE UL2.UserId = UL1.UserId
        AND UL2.Language = 'german') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UserLanguage UL2 WHERE UL2.UserId = UL1.UserId
        AND UL2.Language = 'french')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think as you don't have count and name of language then you should try following query...

```
select userid 
from UserLanguage 
group by userid 
having count(language)= (select count(distinct language) from userid)
```