# Improving a basic SQL query - grouping results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am improving a piece of PHP code that executes a MySQL query.  The query currently produces a set of results like this:

```
id  summary status  date_submitted  last_updated    value
48  test case 1 30  1313755157  1313755252  Low Yield
48  test case 1 30  1313755157  1313755252  28BK
48  test case 1 30  1313755157  1313755252  Yield
48  test case 1 30  1313755157  1313755252  3
48  test case 1 30  1313755157  1313755252  1
48  test case 1 30  1313755157  1313755252  n/a
```

`Value` will always be different but all the other fields will be the same value.  I want to transform the above to look like this

```
id  summary status  date_submitted  last_updated value1, value2, value3, value4, value5
48  test case 1 30  1313755157  1313755252      Low Yield 28BK Yield 3    1         n/a
```

so each of the values have their own column too.  I don't think I need to paste the massive query that gets the first result?  I guess people can treat the result as a table and come up with a query from that?  I'll post the original query if requested.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Just to help the discussion, these operations are typically referred to in the SQL Server world are PIVOT/UNPIVOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do exactly that, but you can do a comma separated list of values. See this question:

[How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

You would write something like:

```
SELECT
  id,
  summary,
  status,
  date_submitted,
  last_updated,
  GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ',') as values
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  id,
  summary,
  status,
  date_submitted,
  last_updated
```

In this case, values would take on the value "Low Yield,28BK,Yield,3,1,n/a".

Answer (score 0):

You could use a set of case when and column aliases:

```
Select Case value = 'Low Yield' then 'Low Yield' else NULL END as LowYieldCol,
Case value = 'Yield' then 'Yield' else NULL END as YieldCol,
......
```

and so on

Comment: Hey, things like 'Low Yield' could be like 100 different things though.  Sorry!