# Getting random friend of friend with mutual count

Tags: mysql

I have a user and a friend table. User having user details and friend has friends of users. Here is the schema of user table..

```
create table smsusers(
  id varchar(60),
  password varchar(50) not null,
  fname varchar(30) not null,
  lname varchar(30),
  mailid varchar(50) not null,
  gender varchar(10) not null,
  primary key(id)
);
```

and friend table..

```
create table friends_list(
  friend_of varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  friends_id varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  friendship_status varchar(30),
  friendship_date timestamp NOT NULL,
  primary key(friend_of,friends_id),
  foreign key(friend_of) references smsusers(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Profile pic

```
create table profile_pic(pic_id varchar(200),profile_pic_path varchar(1000),small_pic_path varchar(1000),
adddate varchar(100),userid varchar(60),foreign key(userid) references smsusers(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
primary key(pic_id));
```

**Here I want to fetch random 5 friend of friend with mutual friend count**

I tried this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ff.friends_id,
   concat(u.fname,' ',u.lname),
   pp.small_pic_path,
   count(*) AS mutual_friend_count
    FROM
    friends_list f
    JOIN friends_list ff
    ON ff.friend_of =f.friends_id
    LEFT JOIN smsusers u
    ON
    u.id=ff.friends_id
    LEFT JOIN profile_pic pp
    ON
    ff.friends_id=pp.userid
    WHERE f.friend_of = 1
    AND ff.friends_id NOT IN (1)
GROUP BY friends_id
```

This query showing friend of friend and also my friends, and mutual count is also not correct.
Query that I [tried](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7581/4).

Comment: Can you construct a query that shows friends of friends and respective counts, irrespective of 'mutuality'?

Comment: I was trying plese [see](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7581/4)

Answer (score 1):

`RAND()` function in MySQL returns a random floating-point value and you can also retrieve rows in random order like this:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM tbl_name 
 ORDER BY RAND();
```

So re-writing your query to show the friend's of each user and their count, randomly chosen:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT u.id,
          CONCAT(u.fname,' ',u.lname) AS 'User',
          GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(f.fname,' ',f.lname) SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'Friends',
          COUNT(*) AS mutual_friend_count
     FROM smsusers u
     JOIN friends_list ff
       ON u.id = ff.friends_id
     JOIN smsusers f
       ON ff.friend_of = f.id
  --WHERE u.id = 1
 GROUP BY friends_id
 ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 5;
```

If you use the `WHERE` clause, the query would output the friend's for user Manish Sahu.

**EDIT:**

Another way to accomplish it is to create a `VIEW`:

```
   CREATE VIEW facebook AS
   SELECT u.id,
          CONCAT(u.fname,' ',u.lname) AS 'User',
          ff.friend_of
     FROM smsusers u
     JOIN friends_list ff
       ON u.id = ff.friends_id
     JOIN smsusers f
       ON ff.friend_of = f.id;
```

Then, re-writing the first query using our newly generated `VIEW`:

```
   SELECT f.*,
          GROUP_CONCAT(friend_of SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'FriendsIDs',
          COUNT(*) AS mutual_friend_count
     FROM facebook f
 GROUP BY id
 ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 5;
```

Then, you could also retrieve a list of randomly generated user's friends:

```
   SELECT f.*,
          (SELECT `User` 
             FROM `facebook` 
            WHERE `friend_of` IN (1)
         ORDER BY RAND()
            LIMIT 1) AS 'RandomFriends'
     FROM facebook f
    WHERE id = 1;
```

Additionally, the function `GROUP_CONCAT` is quite useful in debugging such complicated queries.

More info:

- MySQL Reference Manual: [`RAND()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)
- StackOverflow: [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)