# Hackable sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I was running a site I purchased that I thought was fairly unhackable. However, after having an attack, I found it was not. He informed me of the vulnerability, however my question is what user input could have been done to get all the users usernames like he did? Here is the code...

```
$un=$_GET['username'];
$q=$db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login_name='$un' OR username='$un'");
```

I realize that this is highley hackable. Therefore, I changed the site over to prepared statements to prevent this from happening again. I just want to know what he could have entered to get all the users usernames.

Someone posted the script on github, you can find it here:
https://github.com/sat312/Mafia-Game-Script/blob/master/checkun.php

Comment: Literally the first thing google brings up for 'sql injection php' is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php  Completely explains it for you in full detail

Comment: @Deryck Did you read the question?  He's looking for an example that matches the code above... not some generic description.

Comment: Your hacker informed you. How nice.

Comment: @Brad Oh I read it.  And understood it perfectly.  That's why that was a comment and not an answer.  I'm saying he should have put a slight effort into this before taking the time to type all that just to let us show one issue with one line of code.  Give someone fish, eat for a day, teach em to fish...you get the idea

Comment: You are right @Brad. I know about sql injections I just cannot get it to produce a list of user names like he did. Can't get the right query.

Comment: @alexander7567 both Brad and I gave you the input to make your query return all users. We need more information if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Found where someone posted the whole script on github. And updated my answer.

Comment: @alexander7567 For what it's worth:  https://github.com/sat312/Mafia-Game-Script/issues/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
' OR 1=1;
```

In the URL:

```
/yourScript.php?username=%27%20OR%201%3D1%3B
```

The idea is that since data is mixed with the command, you can just finish the command with data.

Comment: Yes but this doesn't produce a list of usernames. Some how he produced a list of usernames using sql injection.

Comment: @alexander7567 This is the general form.  You don't show the rest of your code (such as how the output works) so I can't be more specific than that.  Also, depending on configuration you may have to finish the second query in your injection.

Comment: @alexander7567 You can get creative with aggregate functions and string functions to get data out.  I'm not going to read through all of the code you linked to... that would take awhile.  I suspect though that this code is extremely vulnerable in other ways as well.  In any case, once you control the query you control the output.  You just might have to get creative in how you roll up the data.  Does that make sense?  Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/149772/362536

Comment: Okay, group concat makes sense after looking into it... Maybe as a learning tool to work my way to that point, how could I run an update query on that without spitting put an error. For example, I want to run "update users SET money =1". If a hacker was to come to my site before I changed it over to preared statments would this had been possible? I have really Been trying to learn about mysql security, and to learn that you have to know how a hacker works.

Comment: @alexander7567 Depending on your configuration, it would absolutely be possible.  In many cases, it is possible to run more than one query at a time.  Sometimes though, this is disabled.  No matter what though, you probably have some existing update or insert query in your code that could also be hijacked.  If you found an SQL injection vulnerability you can be almost certain that it was used.  There are automated bots hitting scripts these days that are very good at figuring out your table structure, and then filling it with stuff.

Comment: @alexander7567 Here's a nice update location:  https://github.com/sat312/Mafia-Game-Script/blob/master/preferences.php#L262  It's trivial to change whatever other user properties you want at that point.  `isAdmin=true`, `money=999999999`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You get `$un` from the user, so I can type anything I want and it'll get substituted into your query. It's called a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

Lets say `$un = ' OR 1 = 1;--` then your query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login_name='' OR 1 = 1;--' OR username='' OR 1 = 1;--'
```

What will happen? this gets executed:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login_name='' OR 1 = 1;
```

This will return every row in the table.

Answer (score 1):

He may have used the GROUP_CONCAT statement in MySql which basically groups a column in multiple rows into a single row (see [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field) for more information). He may have terminated the original SQL statement or UNIONED it with his own and added a LIMIT and ORDER BY to ensure his result got returned and commented out the remained of the original statement.

This is one possibility, but there are probably a few others.