# How to group rows in a single sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

easy question i think.

I have this table

```
+-----------------------------+
+ ip | campaignid             +
+-----------------------------+
+  1.1.1.1 | 3                +
+  1.1.1.1 | 17               +
+  1.1.1.1 | 4                +                 
+  2.2.2.2 | 8                +
+-----------------------------+
```

i want to get a query where ip = '1.1.1.1' like this:

```
+-----------------------------+
+ ip       | count | campaigns+
+-----------------------------+
+  1.1.1.1 |     3 | 3,17,4   +
+-----------------------------+
```

I know how to get this done in php, but is it possible to get this result with an sql query?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql

Comment: @Strawberry look at Jared Farrish's answer... do you think it is more efficient to do this in php than sql? thanks

Comment: @Strawberry This actually seems tailor made for SQL.

Comment: You're sacrificing flexibility. That's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
   ip
 , COUNT(ip) AS count
 , GROUP_CONCAT(compaignid) AS campaigns
FROM table_name
GROUP BY ip
```