# Summarize MySQL table entries by Day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a **MySQL** Table with ***4 columns:*** *completedtasks, duration, date and educationDepartment*. My first aim was to show my entries **by the name of the weekday** for the specific day I have. I accomplished that with following query:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(date) AS DAY,
       completedtasks,
       duration,
       educationDepartment
FROM programm_completedtask;
```

Now I want to summarize the information I have, **by the day of the week**. Let's say I got a table with following entries for instance:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| Day       | completedtasks        | duration | educationDepartment |
+-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| Monday    | Some stuff to do      |        6 | A Department        |
| Tuesday   | Some other stuff to do|        8 | Another Department  |
| Wednesday | Some other stuff to do|        6 | Test Department     |
| Thursday  | Being lazy            |        8 | Another Test        |
| Friday    | A completed task      |        8 | Another Test        |
| Monday    | Some entry            |        2 | A Test              |
| Wednesday | Test entry            |        2 | Another Test        |
+-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

I tried several queries, but those didn't give me the results I wanted to have. When I used **GROUP BY** it just gave me on of the entries I had in the table like this:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| Day       | completedtasks        | duration | educationDepartment |
+-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| Monday    | Some stuff to do      |        6 | A Department        |
+-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

This query:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(date) AS Day,
       completedtasks,
       duration,
       educationDepartment
FROM programm_completedtask
WHERE DAYNAME(date)
LIKE "Monday";
```

gave me following result.

```
+-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| Day       | completedtasks        | duration | educationDepartment |
+-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| Monday    | Some stuff to do      |        6 | A Department        |
| Monday    | Some entry            |        2 | A Test              |
+-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

My aim is to get a **result** like this:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| Day       | completedtasks        | duration | educationDepartment |
+-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| Monday    | Some stuff to do,     |       6,2| A Department, A Test|
|           | Some entry            |          |                     |
+-----------+-----------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

So, I want to **summarize** the entries for one **specific weekday** and I want it in one row. I hope that this is even possible in some way. I appreciate the help very much !

Comment: should duration be added 6+2 or shown as 6,2

Comment: shown as 6, 2. Sorry I edited it :)

Comment: I would love to accept both answers because they are obviously both correct but I can just give one this honour :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(date) AS Day, 
group_concat(completedtasks separator ',') as completedtasks, 
group_concat(duration separator ',') as duration, 
group_concat(educationDepartment separator ',') as educationdepartment 
FROM programm_completedtask
group by dayname(date);
```

See this answer: [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DAYNAME(date) as `Day`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(completedtasks ) as completedTasks,
        GROUP_CONCAT(duration ) as duration ,
        GROUP_CONCAT(educationDepartment ) as educationDepartment  ,
FROM tableName
GROUP BY DAYNAME(date)
```

No need to specify SEPERATOR as default is comma character

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that was the default separator.