# Check for duplicate dates in a table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, highcharts

I have a table set up in my database that contains the following columns: id (auto increment), date, number, comment. I am taking the data in this database and using php to plot it in highcharts as a comparison of 'number' (y axis) and 'date' (x axis). The basic functionality of this graph is complete.

In the future I could have multiple entries per date where the numbers differ. ex:

```
date: 02/24/2014 - number: 3
date: 02/24/2014 - number: 9
```

Is there any way I can search for this and add the two numbers associated with that date (so that I only have one plot per date)? My desired result (using the above example) would be

```
date: 02/24/2014 - number: 12
```

Sorry if this is confusing, im not sure quite how to explain it the best either. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or can point me somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: `select date,sum(number) as tot from table group by date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `SUM()` function in combination with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT date, SUM(number) FROM table GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Is there an easy way to do this with strings too? Something like sum() that would combine two strings if they shared the same date?

Comment: Yes with the concat function ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql )