# how to get data collectively from table columns

Tags: php, sql

i have such a table:

```
r_id     date       recipe_name

 1   2012-05-20  Cheese Bread
 1   2012-05-21  Cheese pie
 2   2012-05-20  Spanish Bread
```

I would like to get all the data under r_id 1 to be in a single row how can i do that using Sql.I need to achieve something like this:

```
 r_id      recipe_name

 1    Cheese Bread,Cheese pie
 2    Spanish Bread
```

how can i do this using php too?

Comment: Assuming MySQL, this is one of the [standard duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Can you do it using php then ??

Answer (score 1):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT r_id, GROUP_CONCAT(recipe_name)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY r_id
```

Comment: thanks it worked well,but now How can I display the recipe_names separately as links using php.+2 for chinese speed

Comment: For PHP version you can see the answer by FuzzyTree, no need to re-invent the wheel by writing another answer on top of that.

Comment: Fuzzy uses fetch assoc().Iam trying to use $rows=$result->fetch_object(  ),how can i access the recipe names this time

Answer (score 0):

Here's the php version

```
$query = "SELECT id, recipe_name FROM myTable";
$rs = mysqli_query($query);
$results = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $results[$r['id']][] = $r['recipe_name'];
    //$results[$r['id']][] = "<a href=''>".$r['recipe_name']."</a>";
}

foreach($results as $id => $recipes) {
    print $id . ' ' . implode(',', $recipes) . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: ,thanks but can you please use the resultset from HankyPanky that uses GROUP_CONCAT().Will be greatly appreciated   instead of rewriting the query again

Comment: why did you not include the foreach inside the while loop??Is this possible?

Comment: can you repeat with a $rows=$result->fetch_object(  ) instead.Thanks for your effort.