# Mysql inner join and filter result

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Table 1: users

```
id name
1  name 1
2  name 2
```

Table 2: user_city

```
user_id city_id
1        1
1        2
2        1
2        2
```

Table 3: city

```
id name_city
1  HCM
2  Ha Noi
3  DA NAng
```

Sql of me:

```
select a.*,c.name_city 
FROM users as a 
INNER JOIN 
user_city as b 
ON b.user_id = a.id 
INNER JOIN city as c 
ON c.id = b.city_id
```

Results:

```
id  name  name_city

1  name 1 HCM
2  name 2 Ha Noi
1  name 1 Ha Noi
2  name 2 HCM
```

I want result is:

Results:

id  name  name_city

```
1  name 1 HCM,Ha Noi
2  name 2 HCM,Ha Noi
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` AND `GROUP BY` to get the result

```
SELECT U.id, U.name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name_city)
FROM users u
join user_city uc
on u.id = uc.user_id
join city c
on uc.city_id = c.id
group by u.id, u.name
```