# joing the rows into together using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to join multiple row values from table.

Table name:Item

```
    ID |            item_id |     Value
    1               43          item1
    2               44          item2
    3               44          item3
    4               44          item4
    5               45          item5
    6               45          item6
```

ID's are unique (primary key)
What I am looking to output is a mysql query is something to which gives this output as given below

Output:

```
  ID |            item_id |     Value
    1               43          item1
    2               44          item2,item3,item4
    3               44          item2,item3,item4
    4               44          item2,item3,item4
    5               45          item5,item6
    6               45          item5,item6
```

kindly requesting to give some suggestions

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: here ID 's are unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `self join` with subquery of `group_concat`

```
SELECT    i.ID, i.item_id, subquery.`new_value` as value
FROM item i 
JOIN (
    SELECT item_id, GROUP_CONCAT(`Value`) as new_value
    FROM item 
    GROUP BY item_id;
)as subquery 
ON  subquery.item_id = i.item_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.item_id, t2.Value
FROM item t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT item_id, GROUP_CONCAT(Value) AS Value
    FROM item
    GROUP BY item_id
) t2
    ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbc20/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value) FROM Item GROUP BY item_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query

```
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.item_id,
      (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t2.Value) FROM item AS t2
        WHERE t1.item_id = t2.item_id
        GROUP BY t2.item_id
      ) AS Value
 FROM item AS t1
```

Demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbc20/18/0