# Mysql get values from all rows but in one record by comma separated

Tags: mysql, concatenation

```
Below is my table

-----------------------------------
|id|     |Zone|    |State         |
--------------------------
|1|     |Zone1|    | State1,State2|

|2|     |Zone2|    | State3,State4|

|3|     |Zone3|    | State5|
```

I  try with group concatenate it shows 3 different records, I want in one record all concatenated by comma like

```
State1, State2, State3, State4, State5
```

I  try with this query

```
select group_concat(state separator ',') as state from zone group by title
```

Comment: And the problem is?...(drums)

Comment: ... Normalisation - or lack thereof.

Comment: Your query has "group by title" but there is no title column in your table. Can you show your full table or better still make an SQL Fiddle.

Comment: GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL : http://stackoverflow.com/q/149772/3835843

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please tell me what is "title" field in your table.
You can try `select group_concat(state separator ',') as state from zone`. Do not use `group by title`.

Answer (score 3):

Group By title

```
SELECT group_concat(state) as State 
FROM zone GROUP BY title;
```

To get all data in comma separated data in single row

```
SELECT group_concat(state) as State 
FROM zone;
```

> Refer : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d5aa/1