# SQL hide duplicate results

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have 2 tables

- tb1 - scene
- tb2 - characters

What I am rying to do is

```
(tb1)scene             (tb2)charaters

(tb1)1                  (tb2)jhon
                             mary
                             charles
                             etc...
```

But I am getting this

```
(tb1)1            (tb2) jhon,
(tb1)1            (tb2) mary,
(tb1)1            (tb2) charles,
(tb1)1            (tb2)etc...,
```

How can I "hide" the dup results on table 1?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Those are not duplicates. That's exactly how sql join works. Maybe you mean how can you group all those records and have all the strings concatenated together

Comment: Please edit your question to make this understandable. Add the proper DBMS tag, add your SQL instructions and format your code.

Comment: @ThomasG, please, no parentheses for `DISTINCT`! It's not a function!!!

Comment: lol... guys calm down. I did not even terminate my comment edition and finally removed that part even before you commented on that detail mistake...

Comment: What you are trying to do is the presentation issue. You need to do it in the front end application when you show the data

Comment: @Armando - Please specify which DBMS so we can help you solve the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: It looks like this is the answer im lookin for. The concat.. Ill try this, and be back later to comment.

Comment: well, not that... Im using the RADbuilder with a .mdb database the problem is that the reports in RADbuilder dont have the hide dupes. Im crackin my head with this... and yes... Its a presentation issue... thanks guys. Any sugestions?

Comment: im currently using this query SELECT  personagens.personagem,producao.EP,producao.CENA
FROM personagens
INNER JOIN producao
ON personagens.ID=producao.ID

Comment: well. None off the trying worked. I just opted to let the report a little more extensive, using a header and 2 subdetails... Works just fine. Maybe ill come around with another solution later. Thanks to you all guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  case ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by scene order by scene) 
when 1 then scene else '' end scene_norm, 
characters 
from tb2 join tb1 on [join clause]
order by scene
```

Tested on other tables, I hope I didn't mix anything.