# How to write a query to get different row's column value by comma separated into a single row in php

Tags: php, mysql

after executing this query:

```
`select A.idrequirement , A.title  , A.location , A.companyname,
 A.createdby, B.assignto from " . $_schema . ".requirement A, 
req_assignto_link B where A.createdby = '".$user."' and 
A.idrequirement=B.sourceid order by A.createdon`  ;
```

I got something like this:

idrequirement   title    location  companyname  createdby  assignto

```
25         Android   Banglore  Barclays     mangesh    ninad 
25         Android   Banglore  Barclays     mangesh    mangesh
```

but I want something like this,

idrequirement  | title  | location | companyname | createdby | assignto

```
25         | Android | Banglore  | Barclays  | mangesh   | ninad,mangesh
```

can anyone please tell how to do this?

Comment: This is the possible solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

We can use MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this purpose:

```
SELECT idrequirement,
       title,
       location,
       companyname,
       createdby,
       GROUP_CONCAT(assignto) AS assignto
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY idrequirement,
         title,
         location,
         companyname,
         createdby
```

`GROUP_CONCAT()` will aggregate all values of the column specified as input using CSV format, for each group in the query.

Comment: Why group by is required for all columns?

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this

```
"select A.idrequirement , A.title , A.location , A.companyname, A.createdby,
GROUP_CONCAT(B.assignto) AS assignto 
FROM " . $_schema . ".requirement A, req_assignto_link B
WHERE A.createdby = '".$user."' and A.idrequirement=B.sourceid
GROUP BY A.idrequirement ";
```

Comment: This query is logically incorrect (though it _might_ run, even successfully, on certain versions of MySQL) because you are selecting non aggregate columns, while grouping only by the `idrequirement`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen idrequirement is here an index column and he is joining different table based on that. So, group by on it its not an issue. And usage of group by is dependent on the requirement. What you said is historically correct.

Comment: Your comment makes no sense, and this should not be the accepted answer, but I cannot control this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You can search for it...if you feel my answer is not satisfactory... and share some links....to clarify your point.