# How to concatenate strings into a new column based on GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, string, concatenation, aggregate

I have a similar question to [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql) , however for this example for  `mytable` table

```
id    string    aggr
1          A    NULL
1          B    NULL
2          F    NULL
```

The difference is I need to update the table to get this results:

```
id    string   aggr
1          A   A|B|
1          B   A|B|
5          C   C|E|C|
5          E   C|E|C|
5          C   C|E|C|
2          F   F|
```

As result the same `id` we have the same `newcolumn` values.

It is absolutely fine to add a delimiter `|`at the very end of the string. That way I can even faster count how many "items" are in the `newcolumn` without adding `+1` because of the absense at the very end (just in between). Also I won't care about validation (if I have a pipe right before) when appending another part or two into `aggr` column.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you actually need to update a table, or just show the results in a view?  You could use group_concat to combine multiple rows into 1 and actually use a count function to count the number of strings for a given ID.

Comment: Yes, I need to update a table. And yes, I understand the table will have redundant data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query :

```
UPDATE my_table t
SET aggr = (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.string SEPARATOR '|'), '|')
        FROM my_table t2
        WHERE t2.id = t.id
   ) AS X
)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I get an SQL Error (1093): Table 't' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data.

Comment: Could you give me the query you run ?

Comment: The same as yours (created a my_table table with these column names). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could  a group_concat joined  on original table

```
select a.id, a.string ,  b.aggr
from my_table a
inner join  (
  select id, group_concat(string SEPARATOR '|') as aggr
  from my_table 
  group by  id 
) b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Sorry, it is SELECT, but UPDATE was asked in the question. Thank you.