# How to show multiple child records for one parent record in an HTML table

Tags: php, html

If I had a database table containing an item and whatever was wrong with that item, for example:

```
Car    Scratch
Car    Dent
Car    Rust
Bike   Broken light
Bike   Rust
```

How would I display this in an HTML table in the following format:

```
Car    Scratch, Dent, Rust
Bike   Broken light, Rust
```

To be insert into an HTML table as:

```
<tr>$name(Car)</tr>
<tr>$defects(scratch, dent, rust)</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can update your mysql query which select your item_name using your category as like your requirement

```
SELECT category, GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(item as CHAR)) as item_name FROM `table_name` group by category;
```

this is your final query

```
SELECT tank_no, GROUP_CONCAT(ng_id) as item_name FROM non_green GROUP BY `tank_no`;
```

where category is car,bike etc and item is scratch, dent, rust

so when you select this then you can print category and item_name and no need to process in php section.Check this attach file

[image: checkthis]

more details you can check this also
[How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: This is pretty cool! But for some reason it is leaving out the first database record and only starting from the second one?

Comment: you can use order by

Comment: Like this? SELECT category, GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(item as CHAR)) as item_name FROM `table_name` group by category ORDER BY category DESC;

Comment: yes it will order by category name, if you want to show car first then use ORDER BY category desc

Comment: Still doesn't show the very first database record. Weird

Comment: can you give me your filed name? first filed and second filed?

Comment: SELECT `tank_no`, GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(`ng_id` as CHAR)) as `item_name` FROM `non_green` GROUP BY `tank_no

Comment: SELECT tank_no, GROUP_CONCAT(ng_id) as item_name FROM non_green GROUP BY `tank_no`;

Comment: Thank you. That still only shows 2 out of 3 database records

Comment: if you want to show more then select other filed also

Comment: easier for me just to show you with text. 

The database data looks like this:

[code]Car    Scratch
Car    Dent
Car    Rust
Bike   Broken light
Bike   Rust
Plane   Dent[code]

In my <tr> it displays everything except Plane Dent

Comment: I don't know how to format what I am trying to post here

Comment: I can't seem to get the formatting right so just put my problem into JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dn5r3rgz/#&togetherjs=GJnw7B4ihv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139526/discussion-between-shafiqul-islam-and-jonathan).

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139526/discussion-between-shafiqul-islam-and-jonathan

Comment: Okay, please check PM