# How to use GROUP_CONCAT function on MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

How can I use the GROUP_CONCAT function on MSSQL while MySQL is running?

```
current table;
     QUESTION_ID    ANSWER_ID   USER
1.        1             1       A
2.        1             1       B
3.        1             2       C

i need;

     QUESTION_ID    ANSWER_ID   USER
1.        1             1       A, B
2.        1             2       C
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: view this [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql) , i think this is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select distinct t1.QUESTION_ID, t1.ANSWER_ID
  STUFF((SELECT distinct '' + t2.USER
         from yourtable t2
         where t1.ANSWER_ID= t2.ANSWER_ID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'') data
from yourtable t1;
```

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent function could be STRING_AGG for SQL Server 2017 and later.
Note that this function not support DISTINCT filtering.

```
select QUESTION_ID, ANSWER_ID, STRING_AGG(USER, ', ') as USER
from t1
group by QUESTION_ID, ANSWER_ID
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017