# How to merge rows in SQL Server with different values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Can you please help me with the below question with a solution?

I have a table with students' data in as the following:

| Name | Course | Address | Email | Contact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Venu Gopal N | CPA | Hyderabad | test@gmail.com | 999999999 |
| Venu Gopal N | CMA | Hyderabad | test@gmail.com | 999999999 |
| Venu N | CPA | Hyderabad | test1@gmail.com | 999999988 |
| Venu N | EA | Hyderabad | test1@gmail.com | 999999988 |
| Venu N | DA | Hyderabad | test1@gmail.com | 999999988 |

Now I want this table to be displayed as the following:

| Name | Course | Address | Email | Contact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Venu Gopal N | CPA, CMA | Hyderabad | test@gmail.com | 999999999 |
| Venu N | CPA, EA, DA | Hyderabad | test1@gmail.com | 999999988 |

This needs to be done in T-SQL and I have SQL Server 2012 on my system. Can you please provide me with a solution?

Comment: this question is [duplicate] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661496/how-to-use-group-concat-function-on-mssql) , you can use group_concat function.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL Server](/q/194852/90527), "[How to create a SQL Server function to "join" multiple rows from a subquery into a single delimited field?](/q/6899/90527)"