# How to concatenate column values aggregated out of a group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL query that works *almost* perfectly:

```
select ConfirmationNumber, ReservationDate, ifnull(CASE TableNumber WHEN 0 THEN 'UNASSIGNED' ELSE TableNumber END,'UNASSIGNED') AS 'Table', CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName) AS 'Customer', Email, Phone, PublicNotes, sum(SleighSeats) + sum(CabSeats) AS Seats
from Reservations 
where ReservationDate = '2018-1-25'
and ConfirmationNumber IS NOT NULL
and CancelDate IS NULL
group by TableNumber, Customer
order by TableNumber
```

It produces this result:

[image]

**Focus on customer Corbosie... above.**

Because there is grouping going on, there are `PublicNotes` data that I'm missing, because some records are being compressed out of the query. I simply want to concatenate the `PublicNotes` from all records included in the query, including those being aggregated out.

For example, when I query this way:

```
select ConfirmationNumber, ReservationDate, ifnull(CASE TableNumber WHEN 0 THEN 'UNASSIGNED' ELSE TableNumber END,'UNASSIGNED') AS 'Table', CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName) AS 'Customer', Email, Phone, PublicNotes, SleighSeats + CabSeats AS Seats 
from Reservations 
where ConfirmationNumber in ('092550', '764352', '661800')
```

...it shows you 3 records that got compressed into 1 record (due to grouping) in the first query:

[image]

The 2 `PublicNotes` circled in red are missing because they got aggregated out. How can I maintain the grouping of my first query, while concatenating in the missing `PublicNotes` with their grouped record?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: Take a look to https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `group_concat()`:

```
select ConfirmationNumber, ReservationDate,
       (CASE TableNumber WHEN 0 THEN 'UNASSIGNED' ELSE TableNumber END) AS "Table",
       CONCAT(LastName, ', ', FirstName) AS Customer,
       Email, Phone,
       GROUP_CONCAT(PublicNotes, '|'), 
       (SUM(SleighSeats) + SUM(CabSeats)) AS Seats
from Reservations 
where ReservationDate = '2018-1-25' and
      ConfirmationNumber IS NOT NULL and
      CancelDate IS NULL
group by ConfirmationNumber, ReservationDate, TableNumber, Customer, email, phone
order by TableNumber;
```

Notes:

- I don't think `TableNumber` can be `NULL`, based on the logic, so I removed the `IFNULL()`.  If it can be, then add it back in (or use `COALESCE()`.
- I added the additional unaggregated columns to the `GROUP BY`.  This is a good habit for you to use.
- The separator for the different notes is a vertical bar.  You can choose whatever you like.