# MySQL Group By Concatenate

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have two SQL tables. **customer** and **tag** joined on the `customer.id=tag.attach_id`

```
customer
+------+-------------+--------------+
|  id  |   name      |   email      |
|  9   |   Alan      |  alan@me.com |
+------+-------------+--------------+

tag
+------+-------------+--------------+
| id   | attach_id   | content      |
| 1    |   9         | alan-tag     |
| 2    |   9         | second-tag   |
+------+-------------+--------------+
```

I want to output this:

```
+-------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| name  |     email       | content               |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| alan  | alan@me.com     | alan-tag, second-tag  |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------------+
```

Here's my best attempt at SQL for this:

```
SELECT customer.name, customer.email, tag.content
FROM customer
INNER JOIN tag
ON customer.id=tag.attach_id
GROUP BY customer.id,tag.content;
```

Is this even possible without first processing the data in another language like PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: Use group_concat in mysql itself  https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to use **GROUP_CONCAT** as suggested by others on comment area, more specifically (exactly) your query is

```
SELECT `name`, email, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.content SEPARATOR ', ') as content
FROM
customer
INNER JOIN tag ON customer.id = tag.attach_id
GROUP BY customer.id
```

This Query will give you the exact result that you have osted on your post

Comment: Thank you all. I got to `SELECT tag.attach_id, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.content SEPARATOR ',') FROM tag GROUP BY tag.attach_id;` with the other help on here but this was the cherry on the cake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use listagg if you are using sql

```
select c.name,email,listagg(content,',') within group (order by c.name) "content"
from customer c, tag t
where c.id = t.attach_id
group by c.name,email
```

Comment: Will give you the error message, check your query and update, try to run and see

Comment: Thank you. Updated my query.. It was a typo while thinking. :)

Comment: `LISTAGG` is Oracle, not MySQL, no?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT customer.name, customer.email, GROUP_CONCAT(tag.content SEPARATOR ', ') as content
FROM customer
INNER JOIN tag
ON customer.id=tag.attach_id
GROUP BY customer.id;
```