# can I reform an array with push values / hash data in PHP

Tags: php

My php code is here:

```
    $ora_result = ora_submit_query($ora_conn, $sql);

if ($ora_result) {
      while ($row = oci_fetch_array($ora_result, OCI_BOTH)) {
      print_r($row[0]." ".$row[1]." ".$row[2]."\n");
  }
```

And I got a result like this

```
=============================
2018-06-09 item1 73.8
2018-06-09 item2 83.2
2018-06-09 item3 83.2
2018-06-10 item4 33.1
2018-06-10 item5 80.2
2018-06-10 item6 77.2
```

I wonder if it could reform an array into

```
2018-06-09 73.8 83.2 83.2 
2018-06-10 33.1 80.2 77.2
```

and "item" consider as neglectable. The best way would be array push $row[2] value somewhere else / do a hash on key "2018-06-09"?

Comment: What is `ora_submit_query`? In mysql you could group by the day and group_concat the values.

Comment: Just an oracle submit method

Comment: I'm not familiar with querying with Oracle but are the `group by` and concat functions?

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an array using the date as the key and pushing the values into the array list.  This would look like so:

```
$output = array();
while($row = oci_fetch_array($ora_result, OCI_BOTH)) {
    if(!is_array($output[$row[0]]) $output[$row[0]] = array();
    array_push($output[$row[0]], $row[2]);
}

if(!empty($output)) foreach($output as $date => $number_list) {
    echo $date." ".implode(" ", $number_list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this. And it seems problem occurs at line     if(!is_array($output[$row[0]]) $output[$row[0]] = array();