# how to find muliple rows which has one column value same and add to one row and set to vaadin grid

Tags: java, mysql, vaadin

I am new to vaadin and java.
I have one class has two values like name and adress.
I have list like below

> `john 101
>   doe 102
>   john 204
>   pri 403
>   doe  103
>   john 206`

first column is name and second column is address.Now I want filter list like below

`john 101 204 206
doe  102 103
pri  403`

is it possible to filter?
please help me out!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

How it is done depends a bit on which version of Vaadin you are using, but concept wise they are the same.

You can use either of these:

**1. Sorting**

By sorting the grid by columns [[“name”, asc],[“adress”,arc]] you should get it. That is sorting by two columns, first name then adress. Output should look like this

```
John 101
John 204
John 206
Doe  102
Doe  103
Pri  403
```

**2. TreeGrid**

If you instead want to group the rows you can replace Grid with TreeGrid and put all with John as children of a main object. Then you still want to sort after that I would say. End result looks like this (and arrows can be opened or closed):

```
> John
        101
        204
        206
> Doe
        102
        103
> Pri
        403
```

Comment: i want same answer like i post. is it possible

Comment: I did my best to answer what i thought you were asking. If you want some more details, you’d have to update your question with more details.