# Get data as a list against a primary key in from the database

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have two tables named Person and Visits. Person lets say Ram could have visited many places like Delhi, Paris, etc.  Now how could I write a query in a way that I get Ram and all places he has visited in a list format in SQL rather than in as different rows.

Comment: In that case you want `GROUP_CONCAT()`: [See this question for a how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have primary key `id` in table `Person` and foreign key `person_id` in table `Visits`

so you can `JOIN` this tables,

and to get places like list you have to use function `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Your final query must looks like this:

```
SELECT p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(v.place) AS VisitedPlaces
FROM Person AS p
INNER JOIN Visits AS v ON p.id = v.person_id
WHERE p.name = 'Ram'
;
```

Comment: @divyanayanawasthi happy to help!