# How to display products with multiple categories in a table

Tags: php, mysql, categories, product

I have 3 tables namely product, category and product_category. How can I display products with multiple categories in a table for my admin panel?

```
  product table           category table        product_category table 
+---+------------+      +---+------------+    +-----------+------------+     
|id |    name    |      |id |    name    |    |product_id | category_id|
+---+------------+      +---+------------+    +-----------+------------+ 
| 1 | Cake       |      | 1 | Sweets     |    | 1         |     1      |
| 2 | Chocolate  |      | 2 | Dessert    |    | 1         |     2      |
+---+------------+      +---+------------+    | 2         |     1      |
                                              | 2         |     2      |
                                              +-----------+------------+
```

I tried creating a 'link table' but when I am trying to fetch the data, it gives me multiple rows.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM product, category, product_category WHERE product.product_id=product_category.product_id AND product_category.category_id=category.category_id");
```

It gives me this output:

```
+-------------+------------+  
|product name |  category  |
+-------------+------------+  
| Cake        |  Sweets    |
| Cake        |  Dessert   |
| and so on...             |
+-------------+------------+
```

but I want it to look like this:

```
+-------------+--------------------+  
|product name |  category          |
+-------------+--------------------+  
| Cake        |  Sweets,Dessert    |
| and so on...                     |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql

Comment: Thank you @PaulSpiegel for the info. And also it solved my problem. Sorry I didn't notice that there's an similar question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY`, `GROUP_CONCAT` and joins

```
SELECT product.id AS product_id,product.name,GROUP_CONCAT(category.name) AS category 
  FROM product 
  LEFT JOIN product_category ON product.id=product_category.product_id 
  INNER JOIN category ON category.id=product_category.category_id 
GROUP BY product_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Kerkouch . It solved my problem