# Using a foreach/while/loop with sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following query to create a view. It's currently only grabbing data from two different tables, `subscriptions` and `subscriptionitems`.

For each subscription, I want to grab the item data and output it in the column, the concat function is grabbing one row at the moment and outputting the data in the correct format.

The problem I have is that a subscription can have multiple items, so I need to grab each one and tie it to the correct subscription via the where statement.

How can I do that?

I've read about using `UNION ALL`, is that the right direction to go?

```
CREATE VIEW Sub_Products AS  
(
    SELECT 
    i.subscription_id as "Subscription ID",
    concat('product_id:',i.product_id,'|quantity:',i.quantity,'|total:',(i.unit_price * i.quantity),'|meta:|tax:0;') as "Products"  
    FROM  subscriptions s, subscriptionitems i, customerdata c  
    WHERE s.id = i.subscription_id
    AND i.active = 1 
);
```

So as an example of the output - any with the same subscription id should be combined and the products should be output in the same row.

So the subscription 217 should have in the products column "product_id:253|quantity:1|total:2.34|meta:|tax:0;product_id:252|quantity:1|total:2.43|meta:|tax:0;"

[image]

Sample data from the subscriptionitems table:

| id | subscription_id | customer_id | product_id | quantity | active | unit_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 556 | 230 | 184 | 262 | 1 | 0 | 2.79 |
| 8100 | 230 | 184 | 262 | 1 | 1 | 2.79 |
| 555 | 230 | 184 | 260 | 1 | 0 | 2.52 |

---

This is my attempt:

```
CREATE VIEW Sub_Products AS  
(
    SELECT 
    i.subscription_id as "Subscription ID",
    GROUP_CONCAT('product_id:',i.product_id,'|quantity:',i.quantity,'|total:',(i.unit_price * i.quantity),'|meta:|tax:0;') as "Products"  
    FROM  subscriptions s, subscriptionitems i, customerdata c  
    WHERE s.id = i.subscription_id
    AND i.active = 1 
    GROUP BY i.subscription_id
);
```

Comment: Abandon comma joins and replace with explicit joins.

Comment: Show: CREATE TABLE for source tables and INSERT INTO with some sample data (both as formatted code, text), desired output for this data. Also provide precise MySQL version.

Comment: @P.Salmon Would that be `LEFT JOIN`? My SQL knowledge isn't great so struggling with this

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: `GROUP CONCAT` is useful in this case. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql) out

Comment: @Ergis Ok I've given that a go and updated my question with an attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

If you did so, you would probably notice that there is no `JOIN` condition for `customerdata`.  In fact, that table is not used at all.   And neither is `subscriptions`.

I would suggest

```
SELECT i.subscription_id ,
       GROUP_CONCAT('product_id:', i.product_id,
                    '|quantity:', i.quantity,
                    '|total:', (i.unit_price * i.quantity),
                    '|meta:|tax:0;'
                   ) as Products  
FROM subscriptionitems i 
WHERE i.active = 1 ;
GROUP BY i.subscription_id;
```

Note that I fixed the column names so no escaping is needed either.