# MYSQL RIGHT JOIN and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables:

- users (primary key: id_users)
- centers (primary key: id_centers)
- usersInCenters (primary key: id_usersInCenters, foreign keys: id_users and id_centers)

With the third table I connect the users with the centers, because 1 user can attend to different centers.

And with this SELECT I get the result that I want:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `userInCenter`
 RIGHT JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id_user` = `userInCenter`.`id_user`
 ";
```

With this query I get:

[image]

So, this is actually pretty good, and almost achieved what I want.

The only thing, is that my query creates two rows if one user has two centers.

But, what I want, is to display one row and show the centers in the same field: 8,7. Like this.

Is this possible? Or do I have to change something?

FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fed10/2

PHP:

```
        <?php 
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($listaDeUsuarios)){

        $id_usuario=$row->id_usuario;
        $nombreUsuario=$row->nombreUsuario;
        $apellidoUsuario=$row->apellidoUsuario;
        $emailUsuario=$row->emailUsuario;
        $ciudadUsuario=$row->ciudadUsuario;
        $createdAt=$row->createdAt;
        $id_centroDeportivo=$row->id_centroDeportivo;
         ?>
```

Thanks in advance
Alejandro.

Comment: use this: "GROUP BY Centros" or "GROUP BY Centros ORDER BY Centros"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: @Stanzi1791 i think the answer is there, but i can´t make it work: Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in

Comment: Could you add the php and sql code you're using, and the error it's giving to the original post?

Comment: @Stanzi1791 done! thanks the PHP is a simple mysqli_fetch_object

Comment: How about this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fed10/16

Comment: @Stanzi1791 thats exacly what i want to achieve! but its not working in my site, just updated with php

Comment: Is `$listaDeUsarios` the result of a call to mysql_query?
If that value is false there is likely an error in your query.

Comment: @Stanzi1791 yes, $listaDeUsuarios = $usuarios -> listarUsuarios(); it´s just how i call mysqli. is there any other code rather than mysqli_fetch_object that will work with group by?

Comment: mysqli_fetch_object should work with group by. I've posted my php code as an answer below, it works with the database you provided in the fiddle.

Comment: While undoubtedly 'complete', I'm less convinced that your fiddle is 'minimal'.

Comment: And note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "gymtable_test");

//Retrieving the contents of the table
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ucd.id_usuarioCentroDeportivo, ucd.id_usuario, GROUP_CONCAT(ucd.id_centroDeportivo SEPARATOR ',') AS id_centroDeportivo, ucd.rolUsuarioCentro, ucd.createdAt, u.*
FROM usuarioCentroDeportivo ucd
RIGHT JOIN usuario u ON u.id_usuario = ucd.id_usuario
GROUP BY ucd.id_usuario");

//Fetching all the rows as objects
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($res)){
    $id_usuario=$row->id_usuario;
    $nombreUsuario=$row->nombreUsuario;
    $apellidoUsuario=$row->apellidoUsuario;
    $emailUsuario=$row->emailUsuario;
    $ciudadUsuario=$row->ciudadUsuario;
    $createdAt=$row->createdAt;
    $id_centroDeportivo=$row->id_centroDeportivo;
    // do something with the variables
}
//Closing the statement
mysqli_free_result($res);

//Closing the connection
mysqli_close($con);
```

GROUP BY groups together rows with the same user id (ucd.id_usuario), GROUP_CONCAT then displays all the centers for each user id separated with a comma.

Comment: nothing happens
, whatever i print or echo inside the while is stopped

Comment: So what does ucd.id_usuarioCentroDeportivo do?

Comment: @Strawberry i use it so 1 user can attend to different centers