# How to concatenate values from a column grouping by a specific values from another column using TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, coalesce

I would like to concatenate the follow columns X, Y and Z, grouping by ProductToday and separating the values with comma " , "  from my TSQL table.

[image]

As a result I would like to have it:
[image]

Which query should I use to to it ?

P.S: some values from columns X,Y,Z are also Null.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: I'm guessing since this says TSQL that this is sql-server, not mysql; retagging

Answer (score 3):

You can use `STRING_AGG()` in sql server and `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(Z,',')
FROM 
    yourTable
GROUP BY ProductToday
```

For MySQL:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Z SEPARATOR ',') FROM yourTable GROUP BY ProductToday;
```