# Comma separated columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have these MySQL tables:

**USERS:**

| user-ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Saoirse |
| 2 | Gal |
| 3 | Margaret |

**PAYMENTS**

| pay-ID | user-IDs | Names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Margaret |
| 2 |  | Saoirse, Gal, Margaret |
| 3 |  | Gal, Saoirse |

What I need is to update through MySQL the column user-IDs of the payments table with a comma separated user-ID of each user, searching by the name. This should be the result:

| pay-ID | user-IDs | Names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Margaret |
| 2 | 1, 2, 3 | Saoirse, Gal, Margaret |
| 3 | 2, 1 | Gal, Saoirse |

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149772/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: Is it too late to redesign the database properly with normalisation applied?

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad? "**TL:DR- YES**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: @Stu, I saw it, but I think is different.

Answer (score 1):

You should seriously move away from storing CSV data like this.  It goes against how the database wants you to persist your data.  Here is the `PAYMENTS` table, refactored to be normalized:

```
payID | userID | Name
1     |        | Margaret
2     |        | Saoirse
2     |        | Gal
2     |        | Margaret
3     |        | Gal
3     |        | Saoirse
```

Now if you need to update this table to bring in the user IDs, you may do a simple update join:

```sql
UPDATE PAYMENT p
INNER JOIN USERS u ON u.Name = p.Name
SET userID = u.userID;
```

Note that more typically you would always have the primary and foreign key IDs persisted already in the table, and rather you would be bringing in the names.

Comment: I know this is not the way to work with databases, but it's an old table that I need to fix like this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET` to accomplish the task, even though I agree that you should normalize your data.

Try:

```
update payments p 
inner join (
             select pay_id,group_concat(u.user_id separator ',') as user_id
             from payments p1
             inner join users u on FIND_IN_SET(u.name,p1.names) 
             group by pay_id
         ) as p2 on p.pay_id=p2.pay_id
set p.user_id=p2.user_id ;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30fadd8dc0d220d857931c1cd334eec4)

If `Names` columns have spaces you can change the join condition to `FIND_IN_SET(u.name,replace(p1.names,' ',''))` or better run an update first replacing the spaces , because find_in_set has low performance.

Check the [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=49e2bbdad11c7215937802959ec941b9)